# Shopify Liquid - Is it possible to create an array of product variants and access the properties?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, shopify, liquid

I need to save some product variants in an array and then I need to retrieve the values of the variants like the title or if it's available or not. I tought I had done it correctly but I can't access anything inside the variants.

I tried doing this:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% assign colorValue = variant.options[1] %} <!-- variant.options[1] is the color -->
    {% if colorValue == 'BLUE'%}
        {% unless blueVariants contains variant %}
            {% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | join: ',' %}
            {% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | append: ',' | append: variant %}
            {% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | split: ',' %}
        {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for variantBlue in blueVariants %}
    <script>
        console.log("{{ variantBlue }}"); //this prints ProductVariantDrop
        console.log("{{ variantBlue.title }}"); //this prints nothing, just an empty space
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong? I struggled to find a way to populate the array, I tried many times and in the end I found this solution on another piece of code in my theme that seemed to work but I don't understand it fully and also I think it's the cause of the problem.

/// Edit

After a lot of research I came to the conclusion that there isn't a way of doing this just using liquid, I'm NOT using Jekyll so I don't have access to the push filter

I'm changing the question in: is there a way to do this using javascript or something else that allows me to retrieve only the product variants that have a certain color and for each variant retrieve the properties like the title and if it's available?

Answer (score -2):

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the issue lies in how you populate the blueVariants array. The problem is with these lines:

```
{% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | join: ',' %}
{% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | append: ',' | append: variant %}
{% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | split: ',' %}
```

- Initially, blueVariants is empty, so blueVariants | join: ',' will return an empty string.
- Next, you append ',' and variant to the empty string, resulting in a string like ",variant".
- Then, you use split: ',' on this string, but since the string starts with a comma, the resulting array will have an empty string as its first element and the variant as its second element.

To fix this, you can simplify the code by using the push liquid filter, which allows you to add elements to an array directly. Here's the modified code:

```
{% assign blueVariants = '' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% assign colorValue = variant.options[1] %}
  {% if colorValue == 'BLUE' %}
    {% unless blueVariants contains variant %}
      {% assign blueVariants = blueVariants | push: variant %}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for variantBlue in blueVariants %}
  <script>
    console.log("{{ variantBlue }}");
    console.log("{{ variantBlue.title }}");
  </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: push doesn't work, the array blueVariants has 0 elements in it. It enters the for and the unless correctly but push doesn't add anything to the array.